# Connect swagger to Laravel passport

Tags: php, laravel, swagger, laravel-passport

I am using Laravel's Passport to generate Password Grant Tokens for my clients. And I am having trouble connecting my swagger to authenticate the calls. Swaggers documentation does not extend too much on password connection set up. So I would really apreciate if someone who had the same issue could share what work for them.

This is my fail configuration so far.

```
  securityDefinitions:
      oauth:
        type: oauth2
        tokenUrl: 'http://api.com/oauth/token'
        flow: password
        scopes:
          some_scope: create something
```

So, I am getting the form that I was specting, but it just fails to connect. Thanks in advance, If I get this to work I will put it here as this is driving me crazy.

Error:

```
Auth errorTypeError: Failed to fetch
```

Comment: Check this article which may help you. https://www.phparticles.com/laravel/how-to-use-darkaonline-l5-swagger-in-laravel/ & https://www.phparticles.com/laravel/laravel-swagger-authenticate-users-via-bearer-token/

Answer (score 1):

You should follow this guidelines to setup Swagger in Laravel with Passport authentication and much more

https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger

Here, some listed issues that you may face during implementation.

https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger/issues/57